# Add a custom attribute to each Wordpress Image added by Gutenberg

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I try to add a custom attribute to every image which was placed with the Gutenberg Editor.

**What I need for each image**

`<img src="#" data-custom="image-caption" />`

**What I tried**

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'add_custom_image_data_attributes', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_image_data_attributes( $attr, $attachment, $size ) {
    $attr['data-custom'] = 'My image caption';
    return $attr;
}
```

But this has no effect. And how could I retrieve the caption for the specific image as variable?

Comment: Not sure about the first part, but you can get the caption by using `wp_get_attachment_caption($attachment->ID)`

Comment: But seems that `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` is not working with Gutenberg images...

Comment: I understand and I'm not sure why.. but I thought I might as well answer the second part of your question.

Comment: You need BlockFilters for that.